# What is the purpose of the 'install' command?

Tags: command-line, make, cp

I've seen the `install` command used in a lot of Makefiles, and its existence and usage are kind of confusing. From the manpages, it seems like a knockoff of `cp` with less features, but I assume it wouldn't be used unless it had some advantage over `cp`. What's the deal?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`install` not only copies files but also changes its ownership and permissions and optionally removes debugging symbols from executables. It combines `cp` with `chown`, `chmod` and `strip`. It's a convenient higher-level tool to that accomplishes a common sequence of elementary tasks.

An advantage of `install` over `cp` for installing executables is that if the target already exists, it removes the target file and creates a new one. This gets rid of any current properties such as access control lists and capabilities, which can be seen both as an upside and as a downside. When updating executables, if there are running instances of this executable, they keep running unaffected. In contrast, `cp` updates the file in place if there is one. On most Unix variants, this fails with the error EBUSY¹ if the target is a running executable; on some it can cause the target to crash because it loads code sections dynamically and modifying the file causes nonsensical code to be loaded.

[`install`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install&sektion=1&manpath=4.3BSD+NET%2F2) is a BSD command (added in [4.2BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4.2BSD#VAX_versions), i.e. in the early 1980s). It has not been adopted by POSIX.

¹  <sub>“Text file busy”. In this context, “text file” means “binary executable file”, for [obscure historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282506/where-did-the-text-segment-get-its-name).</sub>

Answer (score 10):

It provides a standardized way of manipulating a file's or directory's ownership and permissions while copying the file or creating the directory, in a single command.

Comment: It's not atomic. Atomic means there are no intermediate states visible to other processes. `install` does a copy followed by chown and chmod, all separate syscalls, and doesn't use rename-into-place (at least as of coreutils 8.13 the GNU version doesn't). If you assume it all happens atomically, you might get a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 3):

With `install` command we can Copy file with desire permissions

Example which mostly use while setting up ldap

```
install -o ldap -g ldap /etc/openldap/DB_CONFIG_EXAMPLE  /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG
```

This save us doing `chown ldap. /var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG`, if you copied using `cp` then you also need to `chown` in this scenario

Answer (score -1):

See the man page for `install`:

```
$ man install
```

*excerpt*

```
SYNOPSIS
       install [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       install [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       install [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
       install [OPTION]... -d DIRECTORY...


DESCRIPTION
       This  install  program  copies  files  (often just compiled) into 
       destination locations you choose.  If you want to download and
       install a ready-to-use package on a GNU/Linux system, you should instead 
       be using a package manager like yum(1) or apt-get(1).

       In the first three forms, copy SOURCE to DEST or multiple SOURCE(s) to 
       the existing DIRECTORY, while  setting  permission  modes and 
       owner/group.  In the 4th form, create all components of the given 
       DIRECTORY(ies).

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
```

Other useful things such as installing with specific ownership, permissions, and preserving the original files timestamps can also be achieved through the use of `install`.

```
   -g, --group=GROUP
          set group ownership, instead of process' current group

   -m, --mode=MODE
          set permission mode (as in chmod), instead of rwxr-xr-x

   -o, --owner=OWNER
          set ownership (super-user only)

   -p, --preserve-timestamps
          apply access/modification times of SOURCE files to corresponding 
          destination files
```

#### References

- [install man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install)

Comment: As I said in the question, I read the main page; it left me unenlightened as to what this adds to the functionality of cp.

Comment: slm highlighted the specific functionality that sets the two apart: you can set specific owner, group, and mode for the destination file with `install`, rather than just preserving existing permissions as with `cp`