# Installer for applications in LInux

Tags: software-installation

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer#Installer) says

> An installation program or installer is a computer program that
>   installs files, such as applications, drivers, or other software, onto
>   a computer.
>
> Some installers are specifically made to install the files they
>   contain; other installers are general-purpose and work by reading the
>   contents of the software package to be installed.

1. Is an installer always used for binary installation and not doing any compilation work for source installation?
2. Does Linux have the concept "installer" for package installation?
   Wikipedia distinguishes between "installer" and "Package management
   system". In Ubuntu, it seems to me all binary installation is done
   by Package management systems `dpkg` or `apt` - so where is an "installer"?

Comment: For the third question I suggest reading the [install](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html) man page.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu:yes, I have. but I can't figure out

Comment: It's basically just another `cp` or `mkdir` flavor and some installers use it, but by itself it's useless for your purpose.

Comment: The dichotomy is not very useful. It is just a _toolchain_ made of many programs which all have a different function. You can take a package manager like _apt_ on Debian and look into all it's doing to a package and how _dpkg_ is leveraged - ultimately this gets extracted and copied to directories. Installing is an output task that goes down a toolchain...

Comment: @Tim, speaking of toolchains, have a look at the [`coreutils.spec`](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/coreutils.spec?id=2af6179bec2f30a541211d68e3c4e0ebc8b5620f#n213) which is used to build the **coreutils** RPM and see for yourself how **install** might be used.

Comment: I've removed your third question because it appears to be an exact duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141572/what-does-usr-bin-install-do-besides-copying.

Comment: The wikipedia quote is incomplete and ill-formed, as it does not define what it means to "install" files into a "computer". The concept of file is operating-system-dependant already, and some operating system may not require anything beyond copying files in order to make an application ready to use. As @comethapaxd'ajax said, the dichotomy is not very useful, except when you consider the security and reliability implications of letting arbitrary code run to perform the installation.

Answer (score 2):

**q1. Is an installer always used for binary installation, not doing any compilation work for source installation?**

No.  You can actually run a binary from anywhere on the filesystem in most linux systems, you do not need an installer.

**q2a. Does Linux have the concept "installer" for package installation?**

Yes, lots of packaging tools will call installers to install files.  The installer method depends a lot on the language used to write the binary.

**q2b. In Ubuntu, it seems to me all binary installation is done by Package management system "dpkg/APT", so where is an "installer"?**

Most of the time packages that need installation, have a installer script (`install.sh` or someting similar).

**q3. is `/usr/bin/install` an installer or a package management system?**

It is a binary that will "install" a file.  Here are some links describing it/how it is used. It is similar to a copy command that places the binary file where it should be, with the correct permissions to run.

[What is the purpose of the 'install' command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94679/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-install-command)

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/install.htm?lang=en